# Problem in FQL query to fetch shared video

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using this query to find shared videos from my wall and as output I am getting blank array([]).

```
SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=me()
```

I have one videos at my wall. I checked above query here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Please help me to get videos data from facebook FQL.

Comment: You are talking about videos you posted or videos that were posted on your wall by others?

Comment: When user click on "video" link and then they share videos. The "video link" is just above the "Wall Text Box" with a icon of "video camera".

Comment: I know where that is :) Just checking...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly missing the `user_videos` permission from the user's access token. Add that to the list of the permissions you're asking for with your app and you query will work.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the user_video permission is missing, it will show AUTH Exception.. There won't be blank data array..

Thing is you are searching for videos where owner=me(), and that means the video that you own. Actually you need videos that are shared on your wall and not only those videos that you own.